# Calling script functions from a modal dialog gives "Object not instantiated"

Tags: delphi, dwscript

From the following script code, I call the Run procedure from Delphi which calls the showmodal procedure which is also in Delphi.
The global variable sl is not instantiated when calling Button1Click() from the newly created modal dialog.

The Script Code.

```
var sl : TStringList;

procedure Run();
begin
  sl := TStringList.create();
  ShowModal;
  showMessage(sl.Text);
  sl.free;
end;

procedure Button1Click();
begin
  sl.Add('DWS');
end;
```

The Delphi side code.

1) Call Run()

```
FExec := FCompiledScript.BeginNewExecution;
FExec.Info.Func['Run'].Call([]);
FExec.EndProgram;
```

2) Showmodal Eval

```
Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
Form1.Exec := FExec;
Form1.ShowModal;
```

3) Calling Button1Click from the modal dialog using the same IdwsProgramExecution object

```
FExec.Info.Func['Button1Click'].Call([]);
```

At this point I get the error "Object not instantiated". After closing the dialog I get the showmessage with nothing in it.

Comment: Could you post the full code to your form and your script, or at least a full, compilable example that will exhibit this behavior?  Everything I see *looks* like it should work, but if I had actual code to run I could test it and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by the DWS crew. Issue reported and fixed in a matter of hours. Awesome.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was going on, so I emailed Eric about it and he fixed it. :)